# MC-ACCESS Отключить обновленние данных на форме при открытии

Tags: vba, ms-access

На форме есть текстовое поле, кнопка, подчиненная форма. В текстовом поле пишу критерий (например город), жму кнопку и ожидаю в подчиненной форме отображения результатов запроса. *ИсточникЗаписей*  подчиненной формы - запрос "Q1" (`"SELECT * FROM tbData WHERE CITY LIKE Like "*" & UCase(Trim([forms].[frmName].[tbCity])) & "*")"` ). Проблема в том, что форма долго открывается, т.к. при открытии пересчитывается подчиненная форма. Как можно отключить обновление подчиненной формы при открытии главной?

Comment: Долго - потому что ваш запрос вытягивает(скорее всего) всю таблицу `tbData`, если в поле `[forms].[frmName].[tbCity]` ничего нет. И если таблица растет, то вам это поможет(возможно) на какое то время, но проблема останется. Особенно, если база лежит где то на сетевом ресурсе

Comment: пробовал обнулять ```frmName.Form.RecordSource = vbNullString``` при закрытии формы, а в коде кнопки ```Me.Form_frmName.Form.RecordSource = текст_sql_Q1```. Все равно долго открывается.

Answer (score 0):

Если связь между Главной и подчиненной формами сделана через конструктор форм,
в атрибуте "Фильтр по пустым значениям" нужно поставить "Да". Тогда при загрузке, не будут тащиться все записи подчиненной формы.
Если в подчиненной таблице есть индекс по полю связи с главной, все работает на порядок быстрее.